# Where's the original webcomic for "Extraordinary: A Story of an Ordinary Princess"?

Tags: online-resources

Where's the original webcomic for "[Extraordinary: A Story of an Ordinary Princess](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NTYCZ9S)"? The Amazon store page says:

> Portland comics artist Cassie Anderson (Lifeformed) takes her webcomic to print

Then there's [this interview](https://blogs.slj.com/goodcomicsforkids/2019/08/15/cassie-anderson-on-extraordinary/):

> The first version of my story (the four pages from college) almost emulated that cover illustration, with its soft watercolors and familiar feel. However, as I continued to develop the story, it took on a different style. The second version I made was an attempt at making a pitch for an animated series, and this largely informed the style of my webcomic. I wanted to keep that animated feel, almost like the comic panels were screenshots.
>
> ...
>
> **Why did you decide to do the story as a webcomic first? How did you change it when you went to a graphic novel?**
>
> I originally decided to make it into a webcomic [...]

So all information is saying that it was originally a webcomic... But where is it? All I can find are what seems to be [the first four pages](http://helioscopepdx.com/cassie-anderson) of the paperback, from what seems to be a company the author works for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the webcomic version only has one chapter, but it is available online at webtoons.com, here: https://www.webtoons.com/en/challenge/an-ordinary-princess/the-beginning/viewer?title_no=2156&episode_no=1

Found by searching for the author's name, which led to her internet handle; CassieDoesArt; then searching for that, and the Webtoons page was on the first page of Google results.